# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - php

Tags: php, dompdf

I hosted a project, but in some part I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console and the content of the page is blank.
i have a table with some data which looks like this: [image: the table]

When I click the pdf icon to get a pdf file of the specified row of a table, it opens a file and sets an id in the url. The code in that file have som implementation of the dompdf, because it displaysthe pdf for that specific row.

I don't know where the problem is because in localhost it is working, but not online. Any suggestion?

Comment: Be carreful with name case and file/folder access right on production server

Comment: Check your server's error log.

Comment: First rule of debuging: check the logs. Unless you are lucky and someone had the exact same problem no one will be able to help otherwise.